# Updating a JAR while it's running

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I only just saw [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BES9EKK4Aw4) video and thought notch's setup was really neat. How do his jars update whenever he saves without him restarting his game?

I know enough Java and have had experience with eclipse but I've never seen this done before and it would really speed my development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notch actually answered your question in the video. At 35 seconds he says, "because it's running in debug mode, I can update it while it's running."

In eclipse, debug mode looks like a green bug. It is located (in the default Java perspective) to the left of the green "run" button.

Comment: +1 for 'pay attention for a *full* minute'.  OK - those are my words, not yours.  That's just how I read them.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Go into debug mode (looks like a spider or whatever) and it will update your application automatically when you save.